# How to fill na values of a column by checking another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, fillna

This image would help better:

[image: This IS a screenshot of the data here]

The column titled passengerId describes the group number and person number, people in the same group are usually families, hence they come from the same planet. So they are some nan rows in the Home planet column and I want to fill it through knowledge about the group number in the PassengerID column.

So I need a code or maybe a loop that'll fill na values in the Home planet column by checking if they're in a group with someone (because they would therefore be in the same homeplanet since they are likely a family) . That's just basically what I need help with Filling the na values in the Homeplanet column by checking the group number and using the Homeplanet of about group member as the replacement for the na value

I've tried running for loops but I didn't even know what parameter to specify. I converted the PassengerId into an array and the same with Homeplanet and tried to other through members but I didn't know how to move forward.

Comment: use `print(df)` to show your DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the description correctly, this example data frame would showcase the problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'passenger_id': ['1', '1', '2', '2'], 'home_planet': ['3', np.nan, '4', np.nan]})
df

   passenger_id | home_planet
0 | 1           |  3
1 | 1           |  NaN
2 | 2           |  4
3 | 2           |  NaN
```

where you want the `NaN` values to be 3 and 4 based on the value in `passenger_id` column.

You can do this with merging the DataFrame with its cleaned and deduplicated self:

```
pd.merge(df, df.loc[df['home_planet'].notna()].drop_duplicates(), 
on='passenger_id', suffixes=('_x', ''))[['passenger_id', 'home_planet']]


   passenger_id | home_planet
0 | 1           |  3
1 | 1           |  3
2 | 2           |  4
3 | 2           |  4
```

**Update after the question has been updated**

You can extract a `GroupId` field from `PassengerId` and do what I originally suggested like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId': ['9280_01', '9280_02', '9279_01', '9279_02'], 
'HomePlanet': ['Europa', np.nan, 'Earth', np.nan]})
df

  PassengerId HomePlanet
0     9280_01     Europa
1     9280_02        NaN
2     9279_01      Earth
3     9279_02        NaN

df['GroupId'] = df['PassengerId'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
df

  PassengerId HomePlanet GroupId
0     9280_01     Europa    9280
1     9280_02        NaN    9280
2     9279_01      Earth    9279
3     9279_02        NaN    9279

pd.merge(df, df.loc[df['HomePlanet'].notna()].drop_duplicates(), 
on='GroupId', suffixes=('_x', ''))[['PassengerId', 'HomePlanet']]

  PassengerId HomePlanet
0     9280_01     Europa
1     9280_01     Europa
2     9279_01      Earth
3     9279_01      Earth
```

If you want to do further checks to determine if the two passengers are indeed from the same family (for example check their names) you can do that in the `apply`.

Comment: Didn't work out

Comment: @FranklinJohnson: if you can, try to explain to your helper _how_ it did not work. Merely the statement that it didn't work is the least helpful fault report possible - that prompts your helper to ask you various clarification questions. Please supply that information in the first instance, rather than waiting to be asked.

Comment: I'm just overall confused with the project, and I don't know what's actually wrong with the code, this is my first practice work as a data scientist and I just intend to clean na values..I literally replaced his code with my features but it wasn't helpful, no errors but it didn't do what I expected

Comment: @FranklinJohnson I saw your updates in the question, I updated my answer accordingly.